# Why do I have to evict my entity from the EclipseLink shared cache before querying with an entity graph will load my lazy properties?

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, eclipselink, derby

Before updating an entity in my Jakarta EE application running on GlassFish 5.1.0 with EclipseLink 2.7.4 and Derby 10.14.2.0, I compare the updated entity to the saved entity and document the changes.   I noticed recently that my compare code was not working with @OneToMany relationship properties and @ElementCollection properties, and I tracked the problem to Lazy loading of the @OneToMany and @ElementCollection properties.  I was able to resolve the using the fetch attribute as follows:

**Fetch Eager Entity**

```
@Entity
public class Container implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "container", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<AssetSerial> assets;

    @ElementCollection (fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Reference> references;
```

I wasn't entirely happy with this solution, because I assumed that the developers defaulted these relationship types to lazy loading for a purpose, so I continued researching and was excited to find many references to JPA Entity Graphs.  I immediately create the following code to force EclipseLink to initialize my lazy loading properties before documenting the entity changes.

**Entity Graph Entity**

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@NamedEntityGraph(
    name = "Container.eager",
    attributeNodes = {
            @NamedAttributeNode("assets"),
            @NamedAttributeNode("references") })
public class Container implements Serializable {
```

**Entity Manager Initialization**

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "MYPU")
private EntityManager em;
```

**Find Method that only Works once per Entity**

```
Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
props.put("javax.persistence.loadgraph", em.getEntityGraph("Container.eager"));

Container managedContainer = em.find(Container.class, updatedContainer.getId(), props);

PersistenceUnitUtil tester = em.getEntityManagerFactory().getPersistenceUnitUtil();

logger.debug("Assets: {}", tester.isLoaded(managedContainer, "assets"));
logger.debug("References: {}", tester.isLoaded(managedContainer, "references"));
```

Unfortunately, the isLoaded test methods only return true the first time I call the find method on a specific entity.  The second and subsequent times isLoaded returns false.  I struggled with this issue for many hours and determined that this issue was that the EclipseLink shared cache was not honoring the entity graph hint I was passing to the find method.   I solved the problem by evicting the entity from the cache immediately before calling the find as shown below.

**Find Method that Works**

```
em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evict(Container.class, updatedContainer.getId());

Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
props.put("javax.persistence.loadgraph", em.getEntityGraph("Container.eager"));

Container managedContainer = em.find(Container.class, updatedContainer.getId(), props);

PersistenceUnitUtil tester = em.getEntityManagerFactory().getPersistenceUnitUtil();

logger.debug("Assets: {}", tester.isLoaded(managedContainer, "assets"));
logger.debug("References: {}", tester.isLoaded(managedContainer, "references"));
```

Now the isLoaded test always returns true, and I'm able to document all the changed in the updated entity.

In summary, I have the following questions:

- Why is EclipseLink not honoring my entity graph?
- Am I going to encountering problems manually evicting my entity from the cache?
- Is there a better way to force EclipseLink to initialize my lazy loading properties?

Comment: You haven't mentioned for sure how you have loaded the entity when the isLoaded isn't working, but seems a bug in the entity graph support. Seems likely to me the data will have been loaded in the shared cache, and it marks the load graph was applied so there is nothing special that needs to be done, but the logic of cloning this shared cache instance for the local EntityManager replaces the eager relationship with untriggered value holders for performance reasons. Or it could be a bug with the isLoaded check itself. Do you get a DB query if you access the relationship without eviction?

Comment: @Chris I apologize for the delayed response.  I missed the email that informed me you had commented on my posted.  To answer your questions, I loaded the entity using the em.find method as shown in the post for both cases.  I don't remember the details but believe that I only saw the DB query during the em.find process in the case where I first evicted the entity.  Should I log this as a bug with EclipseLink?

Comment: absolutely file a bug. Manually evicting the entity from the cache will cause you extra DB hits; If you can live with not using eviction, I'd suggest you try, as this is meant for when you really need to refresh the data. You will want to check if the issue is with tester.isLoaded method by checking if accessing those unloaded properties results in a DB hit or not. I suspect that there won't be a DB hit as long as the shared session cache has the entities still and it can still be read from (i.e. if you don't use update/delete queries directly or flushed change)